# Find the number of solutions for the equation $ 3x+2y + 3z = n $ where $ x,y,z \in \Bbb N$ and $n \equiv 1 \mod(6) $.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

**Problem**: Find the number of solutions for the equation $ 3x+2y + 3z = n $ where $ x,y,z \in \Bbb N$  and $n \equiv 1 \mod(6) $.

Note: I'm supposed to use generating functions. Also, I found questions about the above equation but none of them talk about the modulo.

**Attempt**: Notice that $ 3x \in \{ 3n | n \in \Bbb N \} , 3z \in \{ 3n | n \in \Bbb N \}, 2y \in \Bbb N_{even} $. Denote $ t_1 \ = 3x , t_2 = 3z , t_3 = 2y $. So we'll search for generating functions that correspond to the equation $ t_1 + t_2 +t_3 = n $, hence we'll have
$ ( x^0+ x^3 + x^6 + ...)( x^0+ x^3 + x^6 + ...)( x^0+ x^2 + x^4 + ...) = (\sum (x^3)^k)(\sum (x^3)^k)(\sum (x^2)^k) = \frac{1}{(1-x^3)^2} \frac{1}{1-x^2} $ [ Here I've stopped ].

Then I need to do partial fractions decomposition but the result is terribly long - I'm not sure if I need to even do the decomposition ( maybe there's a shorter way to reach the coefficient $ n $? moreover I'm not really sure what coefficient $ n $ they mean, are they seeking a specific $ n $ s.t. $ n ~mod~ 6 = 1 $? because If not there are infinitely many such n's. In any case, how would you solve the problem?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $G(x)$ is your generating function, then you are looking for the terms of degree multiple of $6$ of $F(x)=x^5G(x)$. Remember that $T(x)=\frac{F(x)+F(-x)}{2}$ will have only the terms of even degree and $S(x)=\frac{H(x)+H(wx)+H(w^2x)}{3}$, where $w=\exp(2\pi i/3)$, will have among those, the ones that have degree multiple of $3$.

Comment: I am getting, although you better check, that $S(x)=\frac{2x^8}{(1-x^6)^3}=2x^8(1-x^6)^{-3}$. If that is the case, you can apply the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to expand it. The $x^8$ looks wrong.

Comment: How did you get your result? did you use partial fraction decomposition on $ \frac{1}{(1-x^3)^2} \frac{1}{1-x^2} $? ( and from there you tried to find x's with degree multiple of 6, and their coefficients would be the wanted number of combinations ). I'm trying to understand what you did, but I'm having difficulty understanding ( I haven't learned about phasors ).

Comment: No, before doing partial fraction decomposition you do the operations above to algebraically filter out the terms that we want. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection). Some people call it multisection, or roots of unity filter. The simplest case is the version that allows you to filter the terms with even degree: If $F(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$, then $\frac{F(x)+F(-x)}{2}=a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+a_6x^6+...$.

Comment: @plop I get something close $ \frac{F(x) + F(-x)}{2} =\frac{x^5( x^0+ x^2 + x^4 + ...)*[ ( x^0+ x^3 + x^6 + ...) + ( -x^0+ x^3 -x^6 + ...) ]}{2} = x^5( x^0+ x^2 + x^4 + ...)*( x^3 + x^9 + x^{15}) = x^5 \frac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot\sum x^{3(2k+1)} = x^5 \frac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot x^3 \sum x^{6k} = \frac{x^8}{(1-x^2)(1-x^6)} $

Comment: That's the first step. Next, calling that $H(x)$, you can compute $\frac{H(x)+H(wx)+H(w^2x)}{3}$ to keep only the terms with degree multiple of $3$. Note that because $w^3=1$, the factor $(1-x^6)^2$ is the same in $H(x)$, $H(wx)$ and $H(w^2x)$ and can be factored out.

Comment: By the way, we are applying these "filters" with the purpose of not having to work with the expanded series. We only need to do the computation with the rational function, the summed up series. We know what would happen to the terms of the series, the terms with degree multiple of $2$ get filtered by the first transformation and the terms of degree multiple of $3$ get filtered by the second.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a solve without generating functions, it only uses the basic fact that $a+b=m$ has $m+1$ solutions.

Let's regroup $x$ and $z$ under the same banner $t=x+z$.

There are $t+1$ possibilities to choose $x,z$, simply because we can make $x\in\{0,1,\cdots t\}$ and then $z$ is uniquely determined by $z=t-x$.

Let $n=6k+1$ then the reduced equation becomes:

$$3t+2y=6k+1$$

Notice that $\begin{cases}3t+2y\equiv t\equiv 1\pmod 2\\3t+2y\equiv 2y\equiv -y\equiv 1\pmod 3\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}t=2i+1\\y=3j+2\end{cases}$

Reporting in the equation gives us:

$$3(2i+1)+2(3j+2)=6k+1\iff 6i+6j+7=6k+1\iff i+j=k-1$$

Which we have just seen above has $k$ solutions for $i=0\cdots k-1$.

The number of overall solutions is then:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\operatorname{nbsol}(x+z=t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(t+1)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(2i+2)=2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}i=2\times\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}=k(k+1)$

> $$3x+2y+3z=6k+1\quad\text{has}\quad k(k+1)\text{ solutions}$$